# how to create sftp account

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I am not sure if this question is relevant to this site or not but i hope i would get some help here for sure. I want to create sftp account for file management. I can only create FTP account from cpanel, there is no way to create sftp account, how to create sftp account ? i googled it but didn't found anything apart from few irrelevant commands. 
I think i need to fire some commands ?? 
Server os is UBUNTU

Any help will be appreciated.

**If you think, this question shouldn't be here, let me know i will remove it.  **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFTP is file transfer over ssh, the users of SFTP are users that have ssh-access as well, so basically they are system accounts. A guide on [how to restrict their rights](http://solderintheveins.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-sftp-only-account-how-to/)
 can be found here: [here](http://solderintheveins.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-sftp-only-account-how-to/)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and link. I have seen few servers allow sftp file access using ftp client, I want something like that. Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @AmitPatil If you want a sftp-only account using chrooted, this will give a good answer, http://askubuntu.com/a/49284/9701  ofcourse, it's possible to access sftp file using ftp clients.

Comment: they must be running ftp also side by side with sftp server, or the clients support both sftp/ftp and the user thinks its the same.
sftp and ftp are two different protocols and each needs a different communication protocol

Comment: This link helped a lot which is suggested by @Achu http://askubuntu.com/questions/49271/how-to-setup-a-sftp-server-with-users-chrooted-in-their-homedirectories